# Keep the elements with particular letters in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I have a list:

```
list=['Nikolas', 'Niki', 'Niko', 'George', 'Kate']
```

and I want to keep only the names that have the letters "Nik"  ('Nikolas', 'Niki', 'Niko')

I tried this code, but I get an error "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable".

```
list=['Nikolas', 'Niki', 'Niko', 'George', 'Kate']

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['name'])

df_1_transposed = df_1.T

df_2 = [colname for colname in df_1_transposed.columns if 'Nik' in colname]
```

Do you know how to fix it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: your columns are the index now not the names (print df_1_transposed) that's why it's not working

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, do you know how can I fix it? thanks

Comment: I think df_1[df_1['name'].str.contains('Nik')] would give you what you are looking for

Comment: I tried it, it only gives an array with true, false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```
import pandas as pd
list=['Nikolas', 'Niki', 'Niko', 'George', 'Kate']
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['name'])
df_1 = df_1[df_1['name'].str.find('Nik') == 0]
```

returns

```
      name
0  Nikolas
1     Niki
2     Niko
```